# What is the principle of Java serialization and why is it slower than other serialization methods?

Tags: java, serialization

Many frameworks don't use Java's built-in serialization method because it's too slow, but I am very curious about why it's slower than other serialization methods.

Comment: Primarily because it goes back over 20 years, and it wasn't designed for speed like more recent serialization methods. Speed is not the only (or main) reason you shouldn't use Java's own serialization.

Comment: So what's the main reason?

Comment: I'm not aware that this is even true. It uses reflection to identift what has to be serailzied, which is where most of the time would go, but so do all the alternatives.

Comment: Depending on what you're doing, one major drawback is that it's Java specific and therefore you'll be having a hard time working with it in any non-Java language.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne Java serialization doesn't need reflection since it's an internal mechanism, not an external one.

Comment: @Kayaman I don't know what your distinction between internal and external could possibly amount to, but it most certainly does *use* reflection, as a moment in the source code will tell you. And if it doesn't, all the more reason why the OP's assertion isn't true.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne well the code I'm looking at (Java 8) uses `Unsafe`. If you write your own object and get to `ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields`, it retrieves the data content from `ObjectStreamClass.getPrimFieldValues()` (and `objFieldValues()`), which uses `Unsafe` and not reflection.

Comment: @Kayaman Come off it mate. Somewhere there has to be reflection, whether called directly or under the hood. Otherwise the task isn't possible. And if it's done under the hood all the *more* reason why the OP's assertion is false.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne but `Unsafe` is a far more powerful tool than reflection, so saying the task isn't possible is laughable, *mate*. You can access memory directly with it. Try to do that with reflection you glorious stackoverflow compadre, you. Not to mention it's faster to read class and object data directly from memory with unsafe than doing it with reflection. That's the kind of stuff you can do when you have an **internal** mechanism.

Comment: The serialization mechanism is also inherently connected to RMI, classloading (due to RMI) , security and other things which were deemed important at the time, but in most modern use cases they are not what you need (e.g. serialize object to JSON or very tight non-generic binary protocols).

Comment: @Kayaman `Unsafe` must include reflection otherwise the task isn't possible. Somewhere somehow you have to traverse the instance fields of the class, ignore `transient`, etc. JSON and friends don't have friendly access to `Unsafe` to do that, so any claim that they are faster needs to be justified. Or measured. And 'inherently connected to RMI' is false. RMI just uses the public `Serialization` API.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne you're right, the transient checks are done with reflection (it is a lot cleaner) and the actual data retrieval is done with unsafe for speed. I didn't claim that serializing to JSON is faster (or that e.g. Jackson would even use unsafe), and not having friendly access to Unsafe hasn't prevented it being widely used. What I meant was the inbuilt serialization protocol has a lot of baggage, so it's easy to [trim it down](https://github.com/RuedigerMoeller/fast-serialization) (apparently even while keeping it binary compatible).

Comment: @MarquisofLorne yes RMI uses the serialization API, but the mechanism is designed like that partly because of RMI. That's why class objects are serialized for example, so they can be loaded by RMI. That's all part of the extra cruft that you most likely don't need when you just want to serialize *data* in this day and age.

Comment: @Kayaman@MarquisofLorne ,I‘m very curious about what will be done when serializing objects with java's built-in serialization and why are other methods faster than it.